# jQuery + MySQL check textbox value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im using Jquery/AJAX , PHP and MySQL to do this program.

I have 3 text boxes (**pattern** , **item** and **qty** also submit button)

**how it works**
(1). user enter pattern, then item., then user press TABKEY .to go qty TEXTBOX.
(2). I have mysql table  **tbl_master** and it containing pattern and items. (one pattern have many items).
(3). system checking user entered Pattern and Item are matching.

this is my interface.
 [interface](http://oi56.tinypic.com/30c66xe.jpg)

i need to add 5items  and 5qty for this form.  (i tried this but it only check first item textbox only)
[example](http://oi56.tinypic.com/10ddtg5.jpg)

please help me to do this

**my code**

registration.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">

    <title>:: Stores-Stock ::</title>

   <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/settings.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
pic1.src = "loader.gif";

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#username").change(function() { 

var usr = $("#username").val();
var pat = $("#pattern").val();

if(usr.length >= 3)
{
$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "check.php",  
    data: "username="+ usr+ "&pattern=" + pat,
    success: function(msg){  

   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

    if(msg == 'OK')
    { 
        $("#username").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
        $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
        $(this).html(' <font color="Green"> ok </font>  ');
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
        $("#username").addClass("object_error");
        $(this).html(msg);
    }  

   });

 } 

  }); 

}
else
    {
    $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>3</strong> characters.</font>');
    $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
    $("#username").addClass("object_error");
    }

});

});

//-->
</SCRIPT>

<style type="text/css">
body{
font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
font-size:12px;
}
.inn{
        float:left;
        font-size:14px;
        border:solid 1px #000000;
        width:143px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#0066CC;
        font-weight:bold;



    }
.qty {
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    width:50px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#0066CC;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

  </head>

  <body>


    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><strong><center>
      <strong>FINISH GOOD </strong>   STORES STOCK
    </center></strong></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="499" align="center" >
      <tr>
        <td width="170" align="right" valign="middle" id="abc4">Pattern : </td>
        <td width="317" align="left" valign="middle" ><input id="pattern"  type="text" name="pattern" onkeyup="twitter.updateUrl(this.value)" class="inn" />
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="submit.php">
<table width="499" align="center" >
          <tr>
        <td width="170" align="right" valign="middle" id="abc">Item  :</td>
        <td width="191" align="left" valign="middle" ><input id="username"  type="text" name="username" onkeyup="twitter.updateUrl(this.value)" class="inn" />
          </td>
        <td width="120" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" >Qty : 
          <input name="qty" type="text" class="qty" id="qty" size="10" maxlength="10" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td height="20px" colspan="2" align="left" valign="bottom"><div id="status"></div></td>
      </tr>
         </table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">


      $( function () {

  twitter.screenNameKeyUp();
  $('#user_screen_name').focus();

      });


</script>

  </body></html>
```

check.php

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table

 if(isset($_POST['username']))
 {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  // $username = $_POST['username2'];
  $pattern = $_POST['pattern'];



include("dbconnection.php");

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT item FROM item_master WHERE pattern='$pattern' AND item='$username'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check))
{
echo 'OK';
}
else
{
echo '<font color="red">Plase Check item <STRONG>'.$username.'</STRONG> again.</font>';
}

 }

?>
```

Comment: so will your form always have 5 rows of item and quantity fields or can it change? Also, your pattern text field isn't included in the form, is it meant to be like that?

Comment: always in 5 item and qty fields. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ok.

First off add the other 4 rows of quantity and item fields and give each text input it's own id, for example:

```
<tr>
    <td width="170" align="right" valign="middle" id="abc1">Item  :</td>
    <td width="191" align="left" valign="middle" ><input id="username"  type="text" name="username" onkeyup="twitter.updateUrl(this.value)" class="inn" /></td>
    <td width="120" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" >Qty : 
      <input name="qty" type="text" class="qty" id="qty1" size="10" maxlength="10" /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="170" align="right" valign="middle" id="abc2">Item  :</td>
    <td width="191" align="left" valign="middle" ><input id="username"  type="text" name="username" onkeyup="twitter.updateUrl(this.value)" class="inn" /></td>
    <td width="120" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" >Qty : 
      <input name="qty" type="text" class="qty" id="qty2" size="10" maxlength="10" /></td>
</tr>
```

Although you might want to change `<input id="username"` to be `<input class="username"` since if id is used it then there should be only one instance of it.

A neater way to print the 5 rows out might be to just write a simple for or while loop in php and replacing the id number of the quantity and item fields with the loop counter.

For sending all these parameters you can just use:

```
var data = $('#form1').serialize();

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "check.php",  
    data: data,
    success: function(msg){
```

to make things simpler.

Then I think it should just be a case of applying your check to each of the 5 rows of forms fields and hopefully that should work.